# Php/Javascript count down not synced

Tags: javascript, php, date, time, timer

I made a php script which finds the difference between two dates and display it as Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds.

Everything works fine the problem began when i made use of Javascript to make the counter actually count down, for some reason the countdown jumps about 2-3 seconds from the echo to the Javascript countdown, i know this is probably because the server time and my local machines time is not synced, this will be a problem how can i fix this so it is the exact same as my servers time?

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime($end);
$days = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
$hours = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%H");
$minutes = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%I");
$seconds = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%S");
?>

<p id="days"><?php echo $days;?></p>
<p id="hours"><?php echo $hours;?></p>
<p id="minutes"><?php echo $minutes;?></p>
<p id="seconds"><?php echo $seconds;?></p>

   <script>
        var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $date2->format('M d, Y H:i:s');?>").getTime();
        var ico_days = document.getElementById("ico_days");
        var ico_hours = document.getElementById("ico_hours");
        var ico_minutes = document.getElementById("ico_minutes");
        var ico_seconds = document.getElementById("ico_seconds");

        var x = setInterval(function () {

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;
            console.log(distance);

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            ico_days.textContent = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            ico_hours.textContent = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            ico_minutes.textContent = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            ico_seconds.textContent = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // If the count down is finished, write some text
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }
        }, 1000);
    </script>
```

Comment: Javascript `setInterval` does not guarantee precision about the delay you set. Browsers actually can have a slight different behaviour there, but understand it as "at least 1000ms" instead of "exactly 1000ms". Also, a javascript countdown client-side can be manipulated by user, keep it for trivial stuff. For server/client sync, this is very hard to solve.

Comment: It is not used for an auction house or similar, but instead a visual representation about when a certain period has ended, so its not important that it is 100% synced but instead just visually synced